# Search over a list and return the index at first occurrence then assign - 1 if value not there

Tags: python

Hi there im a begginer (not great at it) and currently stuck on a question for assignment

question is as follows "Write a function called find(my_list, value) that takes a list, and a value as parameters. The function
searches for the value in the list and returns the index at which the first occurrence of value is found in the list.
The function returns -1 if the value is not found in the list. "

im expected to do it in loop using no built in functions, slice or list methods

i tried for loop but was doing something wrong, any direction or help with be appreciated

```
def find(my_list, value):

    index = 0
    k = -1 

    for element in my_list:
        if element != value :
            index += 1

        if element == value:
            k = index
    return k
```

Comment: Your return is inside your for loop, which means it returns after one iteration of the loop.

Comment: yeah accident there, i still get an incorrect out come however

Comment: Well, i was assigned another test code that imports with one. The outcome sheet shows im suppose to get 3 and -1 

but i get 5 and -1 
Hard ish to explain

Comment: You need to add a `break` (or return) in the second if statement to escape the loop on your first occurrence of value, otherwise you'll actually return the index of the last occurrence of value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find(my_list, value):
    index = 0;
    for element in my_list:
        if element == value:
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1
```